# Separate items into different arrays

Tags: arrays, function, if-statement, optimization

I have code of the form

```
for each item x in array
    if x in areaA
        put x in aArray
    if x in areaB
        put x in bArray
    if x in areaC
        put x in cArray

    if x in area1
        put x in 1Array
    if x in area2
        put x in 2Array
    if x in area3
        put x in 3Array
    ...
    if x in area20
        put x in 20Array
```

where x can be in both A and 3, for example. The checks are seeing if the item is within their respective area.

This code has 23 very similar looking checks and 23 lines of adding the item into the relevant array, so it seems to me there should be some obvious way to clean this up.

How do I refactor this to reduce the number of checks?

Comment: What programming language exactly is this?

Comment: What’s `a`? Are you looking for the intersection of `array` with each of `a`, `b`, …?

Comment: @joris_van_winden I tried to make it generic, but the actual language is a game-specific custom one unfortunately. It is [SQF](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/SQF_syntax)

Comment: @minitech Updated the question to clarify - they are areas, and I am checking to see if x is in an area.
Basically I'm collecting objects together in the same area, but the A,B,C areas can overlap with 1..20 areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by putting the areas to check into arrays, and then looping through each array:

```
for each item in array
    for each area in areaABC
        if item in area
            put item in arrayABC[ foreach index]
            break
    for each area in area123
        if item in area
            put item in array123[ foreach index]
            break
```

Because the particular language I was working with has an if-then-exitWith structure (similar to using a break) and additionally allows you to access the foreach loop index, the above method seems to be the most succinct way.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function, which has x, a, and array as parameters, checks if x is in a, and put it in the array if it isn't.

Additionally, you could loop over the arrays in a loop without the outer loop